# need to create Python regex for 65$ or $65 values

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, price, findall

I trying to use:

```
price = str(re.findall(r"\$[^ ]+", msg_content))
```

and price value is:

```
XX.XX$ \ X.XX$ \ X$
$XX.XX \ $X.XX \ $X
```

Comment: Maybe you want `re.findall(r"\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?\$", msg_content)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r"\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?\$", msg_content)
```

*Details*:

- `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - `$` char, one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `|` - or
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?\$` - one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits and then a `$` char.